# Do not watch own updates of v-model

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a custom component with `v-model` support. The representation of the value inside the copmonent is totally different from the original input, but is convenient to be used inside the component. The responsibility of the component is to transform the value and let the user change it with a sophisiticated form. Moreover, the component should respond to the changes of the `v-model` from parent component, i.e. it should watch for the `value` changes.

My code:

```
export default {
    props: ['value'],
    data() {
        return {innerValue: undefined};
    },
    mounted() {
        this.calculateInnerValue();
    },
    methods: {
        calculateInnerValue() {
            this.innerValue = /* very heavy transformation based on this.value */;
        },
        onUserChange() {
            const value = /* very heavy transformation based on this.innerValue */;
            this.$emit('input', value);
        }
    },
    watch: {
        value() {
            this.calculateInnerValue();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that whenever this component fires the `input` event, the watch is being triggered, causing the unneeded call of `calculateInnerModel`.

Is there a nice way of preventing this behavior while maintaining responding to the parent value changes from other sources?

I could came up with a flag, such as

```
calculateInnerValue() {
    if (!this.itsMeChanging)
        this.innerValue = /* very heavy computation based on this.value */;
},
onChange() {
    const value = /* very heavy computation based on this.innerValue */;
    this.itsMeChanging = true;
    this.$emit('input', value);
    this.itsMeChanging = false;
}
```

But, as you can see, this is faaaar from *nice*.

Slightly related issue on Github: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/1829

Comment: is it possible to do the transformations inside the parent component? this way the child component will just ouput the value and emit the change on userChange

Comment: It would violate SRP. Having it that way nicely encapsulates details of the component internals and parent has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 2):

One thing you could do is keep a reference to the untransformed `value` prop, and then only call the `calculateInnerValue` method if the `value` in the watcher is different from the child component's reference.

Here's an example where the `innerValue` now corresponds to the untransformed value of the `value` prop passed in from the parent and the transformed value is now set as the `transformedValue` data property:

```
export default {
    props: ['value'],
    data() {
        return {
            innerValue: this.value,
            transformedValue: undefined
        };
    },
    mounted() {
        this.calculateTransformedValue();
    },
    methods: {
        calculateTransformedValue() {
            this.transformedValue = /* very heavy transformation based on this.innerValue */;
        },
        onUserChange() {
            this.innerValue = /* very heavy transformation based on this.transformedValue */;
            this.$emit('input', this.innerValue);
        }
    },
    watch: {
        value(value) {
            if (value !== this.innerValue) {
                this.calculateTransformedValue();
                this.innerValue = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

You could also simplify the code further by making the `transformedValue` a computed property based on the `innerValue`:

```
export default {
    props: ['value'],
    data() {
        return {
            innerValue: this.value
        };
    },
    computed: {
        transformedValue() {
           return /* very heavy transformation based on this.innerValue */
        }
    },
    methods: {
        onUserChange() {
            this.innerValue = /* very heavy transformation based on this.transformedValue */;
            this.$emit('input', this.innerValue);
        }
    },
    watch: {
        value(value) {
            this.innerValue = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This. But take care of Object mutations (if `value` is an object).

Comment: Correct, this assumes that the `value` prop is not an object.

Comment: In my case the value is an array... of objects :-) the component collects many similar items in a comfortable way in frontend and then transforms them to the model form before passing them to the parent. But this should work until the references change. Thanks for the idea.